# How do I retrieve data from an array, to an object in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to retrieve the `filename` and `path` data, how do I get into that data? Here I use "mongoose": "^ 5.11.15",

**Document**:

```
{
  ....,
  ....,
  avatar : [
             {
               original: {
                           filename: asdas.jpg,
                           path: /images/user/1231231/asdas.jpg,
                          },
              },
              .......: {
                         .....,
                         .....,
                        }
              .......: {
                         .....,
                         .....,
                        }
            ],
  ....,
  ....,
}
```

I tried a script like this, but still didn't want to enter the data I wanted.

**Script**:

```
const users = await User.findById(req.user.id).select("avatar.original.path");
console.log(users);
```

**Console Log Results:**

```
{ avatar: [ { original: [Object] } ], _id: 6085afb36c3e012d48f7e1f1 }
```

And for the desired results from the retrieval like this

**The desired output in string:**

```
/images/user/1231231/asdas.jpg
```

Please help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access properties from array in find methods,

Try aggregation operators starting from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from array

```
const users = await User.findById(req.user.id)
  .select({
    _id: 0,
    path: { $arrayElemAt: ["$avatar.original.path", 0] }
  }).lean();
console.log(users.path);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/75XVM10oYvg)

Comment: but for ```console.log (users.path)``` it is ```undefined```. How can I get ```/images/user/1231231/asdas.jpg``` as a string?

Comment: what are you getting when `console.log(users)`? yes this will return path in string.

Comment: The output from console.log(users) is ```{ path: '/images/user/1231231/asdas.jpg'; }```

Comment: i don't understand your language, if its returning object then this `console.log(users.path)` should return path string.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate. The output ```console.log(users.path)``` cannot or is undefined

Comment: i have updated answer, can you try lean() method after query and try.